# Winform cannot be edited without fully breaking layout (2017 to 2015)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

As I left home for a weeks holiday I decided to quickly zip+copy a project I have been working on from my pc to my laptop. It is a c# winforms application that I have been creating on my PC using visual studio 2017 community.

My laptop however uses visual studio 2015. If I just open the project on my laptop and run it, everything is fine. However the slightest change to the form (IE anything that causes it to save?) and when I run the application half my controls now anchor off the right hand side of the screen and are out of view.

I can restore the project back to working by replacing Form1.designer file with the original from my zip and rebuilding - but again any changes after that break it in the same way. The bizarre thing is the form looks absolutely perfect IN the designer, both when opened and unchanged and after changing regardless of how it looks when the program is executing.

Completely baffled and thinking I'm going to lose a week of leisurely work - any ideas as to what may cause this? I could try installing 2017 to see if its a going backwards problem but the free wifi at my location is.. lacking.

Comment: can you do a diff between the designer file before and after?

Comment: having a look in kdiff and there are alot of changes - some things just in a different order but its adding margin and padding properties to some components that the original does not have but nothing significant, like 4-8px. However some size properties are experiencing large changes such as the status strip going from Size(827, 22) to Size(1104, 25). But i dont know WHY :( And these changes are not visible in the designer, just at runtime!